# How do i use JOIN with a get_where clause in CodeIgniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get the data from two tables after an "Open" button is clicked from previous table UI by sending an Id. 
e.g.

```
<a name="Open" href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/WellProfile/'.$post->Id) ?>">
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGD9A.jpg)

So I have two tables - namely "WellDataA" and "WellDataB" , I want to get the data where WellDataB data matches with the WellDataA by WellName(column).

```
Example: 

WellDataA:
Id   Platform  WellName
.
.
4      ZE          ZE-A
5      ZE          ZE-B
6      ZE          Ze-B
.
.

WellDataB:
Id     WellName     CompleteDate
1        ZE-A           12/3
2        ZE-B           14/5
3        ZE-C           20/6
```

This is how my query so far, but it ended up error

```
public function get_news_by_id($Id = 0)
{
        if ($Id === 0)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('WellDataA');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
         $this->db->select('*'); 
         $this->db->from('WellDataA'); 
         $this->db->join('WellDataB','WellDataA.WellName = 
         WellDataB.WellName','INNER');  
        $query = $this->db->get_where('WellDataA', array('Id' => $Id));
        return $query->row_array();
}
```

I expect the output would show ZE, ZE-A, 12/3 when "Open" button is clicked on ZE-A. But the actual output is ZE, ZE-A only. Thank you so much in advance!:)

Comment: What error is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, your issue is in get_where() so, i removed it and rewrite it

```
public function get_news_by_id($Id = 0)
{
    if ($Id === 0)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('WellDataA');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    $this->db->select('a.Id,a.Platform,a.WellName,b.Id,b.CompleteDate'); 
    $this->db->from('WellDataA a'); 
    $this->db->join('WellDataB b','a.WellName = b.WellName','INNER');  //changes
    $this->db->where('b.Id',$Id); //changes
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }else{
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no issue with `get_where()` and `join()`. Both functions can work togather

Comment: it will not give any error but it gives him a blank screen, so I said an issue

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This code works on my project

Comment: You're Welcome @aineivyar, Please kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstful I am sorry if my solution won't be a good one,
but I suggest you change the structure of your tables to this:

```
WellDataA:
Id   Platform  WellDataB
.
.
4      ZE          1
5      ZE          2
6      ZE          3
.
.

WellDataB:
Id     WellName     CompleteDate
1        ZE-A           12/3
2        ZE-B           14/5
3        ZE-C           20/6
```

Since I assume that the used model is relational, one thing must first achieved is to make the tables all relational. Instead of connecting WellDataA and WellDataB with the Id from WellDataB inside WellDataA.

Comment: I also try to use your concept and change some of my codes. It helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove some code. Just try this code

```
public function get_news_by_id($Id = 0)
{
        if ($Id === 0)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('WellDataA');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
         $this->db->join('WellDataB','WellDataA.WellName = 
         WellDataB.WellName','INNER');  
        $query = $this->db->get_where('WellDataA', array('Id' => $Id));
        return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your time! I have figured out the codes :)